# Operational amplifier controlled LED voltage (power supply)

Tags: operational-amplifier, led, amplifier, pwm

I am trying to use two APEX PA12A to control two groups of IR LEDs. I have this circuit:

[image: schematic]

PA12A to take the PWM 0-5 V control signal to limit the power supply to LEDs.
The thing is even when the PWM gives 0 V signal at pin 4, the LEDs still get full 48 V power, which by design should be 0 V.

The connections on the datasheet is [image]

Comment: The answer is on the first page of the datasheet, in the lower right corner.

Comment: I hope you only left out components on the above schematic and not in your working circuit.

Comment: @bobflux the first page lower right corner is the external connections picture, but is there any connection I did wrong? Thanks.

Comment: You have to add the two resistors. It's explained in the datasheet. But why are you using an expensive power opamp to apply PWM to LEDs when a 50c MOSFET would do the job just fine?

Comment: @bobflux If the LED is connect with pin1, it seems does not need the resistors. I tried the MOSFET, the LED I am using is to heat a material and the temperature uniformity has to be within 1 degree C, was not able to achieve it, that is the reason to go with power amp.

Comment: What's A0+ and A0- connected to? Direct to microcontroller? If it's working like a usual op-amp, you probably want some negative feedback

Comment: And does -48VDC mean the negative side of the 48V power supply (so 0 volts) or does it really mean negative 48 volts?

Comment: @user253751 AO is from raspberry pi HAT 152, it give the control voltage 0-5V signal. The -48VDC is the negative side of 48V power supply

Comment: The output of the amp is on pins 2 ans 8. Pin 1 is for output current sense. It's obvious from the schematic, but definitely not obvious from the datasheet's explanations...

Comment: So I have the LED on pins 2 and 8, then the LED is not lighting anymore, even the AO in is 5V. Does this mean the in pin 4 & 5 cannot taking analog signal?